# Why is this question protected?

Tags: discussion

I run across [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33464424/how-to-create-instagram-like-feeds-using-xcode-and-swift-for-an-ios-app), which I don't think it's a question that might be abused, given its contents, but still it got protected. I'm trying to understand why. Should this feature be used for popular questions that attract a lot of low quality answers?

[image: screenshot]

Comment: I suppose the reason it was done manually was due to there being two deleted answers by users with less than 10 rep promoting some online course...but if that's the *only* reason to protect this question, it seems dubious.

Comment: Thats the only reason. http://i.stack.imgur.com/oaK6M.png.

Comment: It's legit; there are multiple answers that were spam. I'm cool with it being protected.

Comment: Now we weed into the rationale, is the question suitable to remain open, or should its title be reworded into something *less* broad?

Comment: Maybe it was a mis-click, and they were aiming for the close button?

Comment: @BhargavRao:  It wasn't automatic.  It was done by a user.  If it were automatic, Community would have protected it.

Comment: @Makoto Yep sorry. Edited that. A third would enable auto protection by community.

Comment: @BhargavRao that makes sense, I have less than 10k reputation, so I couldn't see the deleted answers

Comment: I guess this would have triggered the protection http://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/41570?m=28528291#28528291 :-)

Comment: @gnat I don't think it's a duplicate, I don't have 15k reputation, I don't even have a 10k one, to see the actual reason the question was protected for.

Comment: that question explains reasoning used to protect question you asked about

Answer (score 8, accepted):

One of the latest spam answers was found by [bummi](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/1699210/bummi) and reported as spam:

> [!!/report stackoverflow.com/a/35169463/1699210](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/41570?m=28528291#28528291)

in the [SOCVR](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41570/so-close-vote-reviewers) room where the spam was flagged by the regulars.

As spam is often posted by bots on the same question, we (regular spam flaggers) have an habit of protecting a question so it has just enough of a barrier to block the spam accounts from targeting that question again.

Comment: I was about to add an answer, but hey we've got the "official" word from SOCVR :-)